# Android joystick event injection

Tags: android, joystick, gamepad

I'm tring to create joystick server on android like [vJoy](http://vjoystick.sourceforge.net/site/). I tried instrumentation  but even if i signed apk not worked. I dont find any rooted method on internet. I found adb shell input joystick roll 0 0 but delay is very high.

Edit 1: I tried /dev/uinput but not worked. chmod and others not worked (system app etc...)

Comment: Have found any solution, I want to inject joystick events in android. using /dev/uinput  you can only inject buttons

Comment: yeah i found a solution, look at this example https://github.com/razgithub/synergy-android/tree/master/jni